# How to check if mouse is over an object in an array in p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have an array of ants that I want the user to be able to click on and see the stats of that individual ant. I have made an object for an ant and I have put several of those ant objects on screen. Currently when I click on an ant with the follow code:

```
function mouseClicked() {
  if(overAnt(ants[i].pos.x, ants[i].pos.y, ants[i].r)) {
    print('Health: ' + ant.health + '\nHunger: ' + ant.hunger + '\nThrist: ' + ant.thirst);
  }
}
```

It will give me an error stating that 'i' is not defined. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and am very confused. Here's the code for the rest of the project.

Ant code:

```
function Ant() {
  this.pos = createVector(random(50, 350), random(350, 50));
  this.vel = createVector();
  this.r = 20;
  
  let antNames = ['Gary', 'Lary', 'Jerry', 'Berry', 'Serry', 'Cari'];
  let word = random(antNames);
  
  this.name = word;
  
  this.health = 100;
  this.hunger = 0;
  this.thirst = 0;
  
  this.hDeplete = createVector(random(50, 1));
  
  this.show = function() {
    push();
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    if(this.dead) {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    } else if (!this.dead) {
      fill(0);
    }
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, this.r);
    pop();
  }
  
  this.update = function() {
    if(this.hunger < 100) {
      this.hunger += 1;
    } else if(this.hunger >= 85 && this.health != 0) {
      this.health -= 1;
      print('health going down ' + this.health);
      if(this.health == 0) {
        this.dead();
      }
    }
    
    
    
  } 

  this.dead = function() {
    if(this.health == 0) {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
      print(this.name + ' dead.');
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

sketch.js code:

```
let antNum = 10;

let i = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  ants = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < antNum; i++) {
    ants[i] = new Ant();
  }
  
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < antNum; i++) {
    ants[i].show();
    ants[i].update();
  }
}

function overAnt(x, y, r) {
  if (dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < r) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if(overAnt(ants[i].pos.x, ants[i].pos.y, ants[i].r)) {
    print('Health: ' + ant.health + '\nHunger: ' + ant.hunger + '\nThrist: ' + ant.thirst);
  }
}
```

(don't mind the other horrific and inefficient code haha)

If it's worth mentioning I have the ant.js file added to the index.html file so everything is being called properly except for the mouseClicked function. (another note: the mouseClicked function was working perfectly fine when it was just a single object and not an array of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this code, it should always be checking if you clicked on the second ant, because you've defined `i = 1` at the top.
So I'm assuming that you added that after getting the error you posted.

What you want to do is define `i` *in that function*, like you've done in `setup` and `draw`, and loop over all the ants and see if the mouse was on top of any of them:

```
function mouseClicked() {
  for(var i = 0; i < antNum; i++) {
    if(overAnt(ants[i].pos.x, ants[i].pos.y, ants[i].r)) {
      print('Health: ' + ant.health + '\nHunger: ' + ant.hunger + '\nThrist: ' + ant.thirst);
    }
  }
}
```

You should also define `const ants = []` at the top of the code, like you have done with `antNum`.

Comment: this was spot on everything. thanks a ton man.